# ProgressDialog not starting - Android (java)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make simple app on Android.

## EDIT

**New code:**

```
package com.sirseni.simpleandroidwebviewexample;

/**
 * Created by otsma on 26.05.2017.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class Hack extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    // Splash screen timer


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hack);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    }
    private int jumpTime = 0;

    public void download() {
        //initializing progress dialog
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Changing Files");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setProgress(0);
        progress.show();

        final int totalProgressTime = 100;
        //creating a thread
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                    try {
                        jumpTime += 5;
                        // if we have to update the view, we have to execute the code in UI thread. runOnUiThread() gives us that functionality
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // updating view in UI thread
                                progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                                progress.setMessage("Hello" + jumpTime);
                            }
                        });
                        sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }}
```

Now it's working like that, user tap on button, the progressdialog is appearing but everytime it is 0% and 0/100. How to fix it? For example after 20 seconds will be 100% and how to make, that when it reach 100% the new activity is starting?

Thanks guys for help!

Answer (score 0):

Please update the download method by the below code:

```
private int jumpTime = 0;

public void download() {
    //initializing progress dialog
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Changing Files");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.show();

    final int totalProgressTime = 100;
    //creating a thread
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                try {
                    jumpTime += 5;
                    // if we have to update the view, we have to execute the code in UI thread. runOnUiThread() gives us that functionality
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // updating view in UI thread
                            progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                            progress.setMessage("Hello" + jumpTime);
                        }
                    });
                    sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: @AvjitKarmakar it's not works. The jumpTime is underlined on red. And where I can give the new intent run?

Comment: @AvjitKarmakar it's saying - "Variable jumpTime is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: I checked. Eveytime is 0% and 0/100 ;s

Comment: @AvjitKarmakar check the comment above

Comment: @MarkusMaleńki Let me check

Comment: @AvjitKarmakar and?

Comment: @MarkusMaleńki Now, it's working fine. Please update the code.

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar `Please update the download method by the below code:` Explain in your answer *why* and *what your code does*. Copying code without understanding doesn't help anybody.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar i checked it, my app is crashing now

Comment: I checked it. But it's working fine to me. Please update the question with this new code. I will check.

Comment: Please post the crash log. Same code is working fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Changing Files");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progress.setMax(100);
progress.setProgress(0);
progress.show();

int jumpTime = 0;
Handler ha = new Handler();
ha.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call function
        jumpTime += 5;
        progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
        progress.setMessage("Hello" + jumpTime);

        if(jumpTime < 100){
            ha.postDelayed(this, 200);
        }
        else{
            //do code
        }
    }
});
```